# how can I do it

Tags: oracle, plsql

`

```
SELECT TXNID,
       TOTAL_AMOUNT,
       ACCOUNT_CATEGORY,
       DEBIT 
FROM ACCOUNTING_BOOK 
  WHERE TXNID like 'M003%' ;
```

TXNID:M003   TOTAL_AMT:25  ACCOUNT_CATEGORY:Revenue  Debit:null  Credit:null

TXNID:M003     TOTAL_AMT:25    ACCOUNT_CATEGORY:Asset    Debit:null  Credit:null

Rules for populating debit column:[Total-Amount if account-category=Expense or if account-category=Asset for corresponding Revenue item matched by TxnId; 0 otherwise]

Want to validate the result inside this table into debit column.How can I do it?

Rules for populating credit column:[Total-Amount if account-category=Revenue or if account-category=Asset for corresponding Expense item matched by TxnId will return 1 ; 0 otherwise]
Want to validate the result inside this table into credit column.How can I do it?

Comment: Add your sample data and expected output so that people can understand

Comment: Now is it good to go?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood rules correctly:

```
update accounting_book ab
  set debit = case when account_category in ('Expense', 'Asset')
                   then (select sum(total_amt)
                           from accounting_book 
                           where account_category = 'Revenue'
                             and txnid = ab.txnid)
                   else 0
              end
```

---

Edit:

> Rules for populating credit column:[Total-Amount if
>   account-category=Revenue or if account-category=Asset for
>   corresponding Expense item matched by TxnId will return 1 ; 0
>   otherwise]

Similar to previous update:

```
update accounting_book ab
  set credit = case when account_category in ('Revenue', 'Asset')
                     and exists (select 1  
                                   from accounting_book 
                                   where account_category = 'Expense'
                                     and txnid = ab.txnid)
                    then 1
                    else 0
               end
```

Comment: @saurav - if it be done in SQL why do you  want a function? Perhaps you need to edit your question again with more details about your situation.

Comment: And it's not good practice to store values which you can count, because they may become invalid. I would rather use view.

Comment: I just try this but in some fields its returning null values.What is the reason for that? Can you explain me sir..?

Comment: Perhaps because there are no corresponding `Revenue` rows? And `sum(null)` is `null`. You see your data, please check. ;-)

Comment: Rules for populating credit column:[Total-Amount if account-category=Revenue or if account-category=Asset for corresponding Expense item matched by TxnId will return 1 ; 0 otherwise]

Want to validate the result inside this table into credit column.How can I do it?

Comment: please give me a reply

Comment: Answer edited. Please do not change your question, this invalidates previous answer. If You have new questions please create new topics. This is how Stack Overflow is organized. If this answer is helpful consider marking it as accepted. And You should definitely read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
     CASE WHEN A.ACCOUNTCATEGORY IN('Revenue','Asset')
              AND EXISTS (SELECT TOTAL_AMOUNT
              FROM ACCOUNTING_BOOK
              WHERE ACCOUNTCATEGORY='Expense'
              AND TXNID=A.TXNID)
              THEN A.TOTAL_AMOUNT
              ELSE 0
              END, 

               CASE WHEN A.ACCOUNTCATEGORY IN('Expense','Asset')
              AND EXISTS (SELECT TOTAL_AMOUNT
              FROM ACCOUNTING_BOOK
              WHERE ACCOUNTCATEGORY='Revenue'
              AND TXNID=A.TXNID)
              THEN A.TOTAL_AMOUNT
              ELSE 0
              end);


 END LOOP;
 END;
 /
```

Comment: when I'm doing this way then debit column gives me the correct output but credit column comes 0 because it contains negative values.I want to use credit column with the help of cursor without using update statement.

Comment: Rules for populating credit column:[Total-Amount if account-category=Revenue or if account-category=Asset for corresponding Expense item matched by TxnId ; 0 otherwise]

Comment: please help me.